# Calculation based on unit of measure and calculation for sum

Tags: javascript, html, integer, sum

This code is supposed to calculate based on the unit of measure.  It the unit of measure is Units, beds or rooms, it's supposed to give the percentage in the total percent occupied text box of the occupied and vacant units based on the amount of units, beds or rooms minus the amount of vacant units, beds or rooms.  If the calculation is based on square footage, it's supposed to divide the square footage net by the occupied space minus the amount of vacant space.

The second calculation is just a simple sum in the four different text boxes.  Simple as it may be, it still doesn't work....:(

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Total Number of Units/Rooms/Beds</title>
</head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function calcPercentOccupied() {
        var OccObj = document.getElementById("OccupiedSpaceText").innerHTML;
        if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Units' || document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Rooms' || document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Beds') {
            if (document.getElementsByName("OccupiedSpaceValue").value == '' && document.getElementsByName("NumberOfUnitsRoomsBedsCount").value == '') {
                alert('Please input "Total Number of ' + OccObj + ' and "Occupied ' + OccObj + '"');
            } else {
                with(document.forms[0]) {
                    NumberOfUnitsRoomsBeds = document.getElementsByName("NumberOfUnitsRoomsBedsCount").value;
                    OccupiedSpace = document.getElementsByName("OccupiedSpaceValue").value;
                    document.getElementsByName("NumberOfUnitsRoomsBedsCount").value = Math.round((OccupiedSpace / NumberOfUnitsRoomsBeds) * 10000) / 100 + "%";
                }
            }
        } else if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Sq. Feet') {
            if (document.getElementsByName("NetRentableSquareFootage").value == '' && document.getElementsByName("OccupiedSpaceValue").value == '') {
                alert('Please input "Total Sq. Feet (Net/Rentable)" and "Occupied ' + OccObj + '"');
            } else {
                with(document.forms[0]) {
                    NetSquareFootage = document.getElementsByName("NetRentableSquareFootage").value;
                    OccupiedSpace = document.getElementsByName("OccupiedSpaceValue").value;
                    document.getElementsByName("NumberOfUnitsRoomsBedsCount").value = Math.round((OccupiedSpace / NetSquareFootage) * 10000) / 100 + "%";
                }
            }
        } else {
            alert('Please select a "Unit of Measurement"');
        }
    }

    function addOccupiedSpaceText() {
        if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == '') {
            document.getElementById("OccupiedSpaceText").innerHTML = "Space";
        } else if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Units') {
            document.getElementById("OccupiedSpaceText").innerHTML = "Units";
        } else if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Rooms') {
            document.getElementById("OccupiedSpaceText").innerHTML = "Rooms";
        } else if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Beds') {
            document.getElementById("OccupiedSpaceText").innerHTML = "Beds";
        } else if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Sq. Feet') {
            document.getElementById("OccupiedSpaceText").innerHTML = "Sq. Feet";
        }
    }

    function addVacantSpaceText() {
        if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == '') {
            document.getElementById("VacantSpaceText").innerHTML = "Space";
        } else if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Units') {
            document.getElementById("VacantSpaceText").innerHTML = "Units";
        } else if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Rooms') {
            document.getElementById("VacantSpaceText").innerHTML = "Rooms";
        }`
        else if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Beds') {
            document.getElementById("VacantSpaceText").innerHTML = "Beds";
        }`
        else if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Sq. Feet') {
            document.getElementById("VacantSpaceText").innerHTML = "Sq. Feet";
        }
    }

    function addTotalUnitsRoomsBedsText() {`
        if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == '') {
            document.getElementById("TotalUnitsRoomsBeds").innerHTML = "Units/Rooms/Beds";
        }`
        else if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Units') {
            document.getElementById("TotalUnitsRoomsBeds").innerHTML = "Units";
        }`
        else if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Rooms') {
            document.getElementById("TotalUnitsRoomsBeds").innerHTML = "Rooms";
        }`
        else if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Beds') {
            document.getElementById("TotalUnitsRoomsBeds").innerHTML = "Beds";
        }`
        else if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Sq. Feet') {
            document.getElementById("TotalUnitsRoomsBeds").innerHTML = "Units/Rooms/Beds";
        }`
    }

    function addDownUnitsRoomsBedsText() {`
        if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == '') {
            document.getElementById("DownUnitsRoomsBeds").innerHTML = "Units/Rooms/Beds";
        } else if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Units') {
            document.getElementById("DownUnitsRoomsBeds").innerHTML = "Units";
        } else if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Rooms') {
            document.getElementById("DownUnitsRoomsBeds").innerHTML = "Rooms";
        } else if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Beds') {
            document.getElementById("DownUnitsRoomsBeds").innerHTML = "Beds";
        } else if (document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType").value == 'Sq. Feet') {
            document.getElementById("DownUnitsRoomsBeds").innerHTML = "Units/Rooms/Beds";
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
    <form method="post" action>
        <table width="700">
            <tr>
                <td width="40%"></td>
                <td width="11%"></td>
                <td width="27%" colspan="2"></td>
                <td width="22%"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total Number of Units/Rooms/Beds:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="NumberOfUnitsRoomsBedsCount" id="TotalUnitsRoomsBeds" tabindex="41">
                </td>
                <td>Total Sq. Feet (Net/Rentable):</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="NetRentableSquareFootage" tabindex="47">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total Number of Down Units/Rooms/Beds:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="DownUnitsRoomsBeds" name="NumberOfDownUnitsCount" tabindex="43">
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">Occupied Space:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="OccupiedSpaceValue" id="OccupiedSpaceText" value="" tabindex="47">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unit of Measurement:</td>
                <td>
                    <select size="1" name="MeasurementUnitType" value="Unit of Measurement:" tabindex="44" onchange="addOccupiedSpaceText(); addVacantSpaceText(); addTotalUnitsRoomsBedsText(); addDownUnitsRoomsBedsText()" style="height: 22px">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Units">Units</option>
                        <option value="Rooms">Rooms</option>
                        <option value="Beds">Beds</option>
                        <option value="Sq. Feet">Sq. Feet</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">Vacant Space:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="VacantSpaceValue" id="VacantSpaceText" tabindex="48" ;>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">Total Percent Occupied:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="PercentOccupied" value="" tabindex="49" readonly="readonly">
                    <button type="button" onload="calcPercentOccupied();" onclick="calcPercentOccupied();">Calculate</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p></p>
        <table>
            <tr class="style1">
                <th># of
                    <br />Bedrooms</th>
                <th># of
                    <br />Baths</th>
                <th># of
                    <br />Units</th>
                <th>Average
                    <br />Ft*/Unit</th>
                <th>Monthly
                    <br />Rent</th>
                <th>#
                    <br />Occupied</th>
                <th>#
                    <br />Vacant</th>
                <th>#
                    <br />Down</th>
                <th>#
                    <br />Inspected</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="MeasurementIdentifierBedroomsCount01" value="MeasurementIdentifierBedroomsCount01" tabindex="257" style="height: 19px" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="MeasurementIdentifierBathCount01" value="MeasurementIdentifierBathCount01" tabindex="257" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="NumberOfMeasurementCount01" value="NumberOfMeasurementCount01" tabindex="257" onfocus="calcNumberOfMeasurementCountSum()" style="height: 19px" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="AverageSizeOfMeasurementFootage01" value="AverageSizeOfMeasurementFootage01" class="RentAVGFT" tabindex="257" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="AverageRentOfMeasurementAmount01" value="AverageRentOfMeasurementAmount01" class="RentAVGFT" tabindex="257" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCount01" value="NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCount01" tabindex="257" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="NumberOfMeasurementVacantCount01" value="NumberOfMeasurementVacantCount01" tabindex="257" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="NumberOfMeasurementDownCount01" value="NumberOfMeasurementDownCount01" tabindex="257" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCount01" value=“NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCount01 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="MeasurementIdentifierBedroomsCount02 "      value=“MeasurementIdentifierBedroomsCount02" tabindex="257" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="MeasurementIdentifierBathCount02" value=“MeasurementIdentifierBathCount02 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementCount02 "      value=“NumberOfMeasurementCount02" tabindex="257" onfocus="calcNumberOfMeasurementCountSum()" style="height: 19px" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="AverageSizeOfMeasurementFootage02" value=“AverageSizeOfMeasurementFootage02 " class="RentAVGFT " tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="AverageRentOfMeasurementAmount02 "      value=“AverageRentOfMeasurementAmount02" class="RentAVGFT" tabindex="257" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCount02" value=“NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCount02 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementVacantCount02 "      value=“NumberOfMeasurementVacantCount02" tabindex="257" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="NumberOfMeasurementDownCount02" value=“NumberOfMeasurementDownCount02 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCount02 " value=“NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCount02" tabindex="257" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="MeasurementIdentifierBedroomsCount03" v value=“MeasurementIdentifierBedroomsCount03 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="MeasurementIdentifierBathCount03 " value=“MeasurementIdentifierBathCount03" tabindex="257" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="NumberOfMeasurementCount03" value=“NumberOfMeasurementCount03 "  tabindex="257 " onfocus="calcNumberOfMeasurementCountSum() " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="AverageSizeOfMeasurementFootage03 " AverageSizeOfMeasurementFootage03" class="RentAVGFT" tabindex="257" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="AverageRentOfMeasurementAmount03" value="AverageRentOfMeasurementAmount03" class="RentAVGFT" tabindex="257" style="height: 19px" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCount03" value="NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCount03" tabindex="257" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="NumberOfMeasurementVacantCount03" value="NumberOfMeasurementVacantCount03" tabindex="257" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="NumberOfMeasurementDownCount03" value="NumberOfMeasurementDownCount03" tabindex="257" style="height: 19px" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCount03" value=“NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCount03 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="MeasurementIdentifierBedroomsCount04 " value=“MeasurementIdentifierBedroomsCount04" tabindex="257" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="MeasurementIdentifierBathCount04" value=“MeasurementIdentifierBathCount04 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementCount04 " value=“NumberOfMeasurementCount04" tabindex="257" onfocus="calcNumberOfMeasurementCountSum()" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="AverageSizeOfMeasurementFootage04" AverageSizeOfMeasurementFootage04 " class="RentAVGFT " tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="AverageRentOfMeasurementAmount04 " value="AverageRentOfMeasurementAmount04 " class="RentAVGFT " tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCount04 " value="NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCount04 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementVacantCount04 " value="NumberOfMeasurementVacantCount04 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementDownCount04 " value="NumberOfMeasurementDownCount04 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCount04 " value="NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCount04 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="MeasurementIdentifierBedroomsCount05 "      value="MeasurementIdentifierBedroomsCount05 "  tabindex="257 " style="height: 19px " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="MeasurementIdentifierBathCount05 "      value="MeasurementIdentifierBathCount05 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementCount05 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementCount05 "  tabindex="257 " onfocus="calcNumberOfMeasurementCountSum() " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="AverageSizeOfMeasurementFootage05 "      value="AverageSizeOfMeasurementFootage05 " class="RentAVGFT " tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="AverageRentOfMeasurementAmount05 "      value="AverageRentOfMeasurementAmount05 " class="RentAVGFT " tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCount05 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCount05 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementVacantCount05 " "NumberOfMeasurementVacantCount05 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementDownCount05 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementDownCount05 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCount05 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCount05 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="MeasurementIdentifierBedroomsCount06 "      value="MeasurementIdentifierBedroomsCount06 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="MeasurementIdentifierBathCount06 "      value="MeasurementIdentifierBathCount06 "  tabindex="257 " style="height: 19px " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementCount06 "           value="NumberOfMeasurementCount06 "  tabindex="257 " onfocus="calcNumberOfMeasurementCountSum() " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="AverageSizeOfMeasurementFootage06 "      value="AverageSizeOfMeasurementFootage06 " class="RentAVGFT " tabindex="257 " style="height: 19px " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="AverageRentOfMeasurementAmount06 "      value="AverageRentOfMeasurementAmount06 " class="RentAVGFT " tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCount06 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCount06 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementVacantCount06 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementVacantCount06 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementDownCount06 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementDownCount06 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCount06 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCount06 "  tabindex="257 " style="height: 19px " /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="MeasurementIdentifierBedroomsCount07 "      value="MeasurementIdentifierBedroomsCount07 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="MeasurementIdentifierBathCount07 "      value="MeasurementIdentifierBathCount07 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementCount07 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementCount07 "  tabindex="257 " onfocus="calcNumberOfMeasurementCountSum() " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="AverageSizeOfMeasurementFootage07 "      value="AverageSizeOfMeasurementFootage07 " class="RentAVGFT " tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="AverageRentOfMeasurementAmount07 "      value="AverageRentOfMeasurementAmount07 " class="RentAVGFT " tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCount07 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCount07 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementVacantCount07 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementVacantCount07 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementDownCount07 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementDownCount07 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCount07 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCount07 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="MeasurementIdentifierBedroomsCount08 "      value="MeasurementIdentifierBedroomsCount08 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="MeasurementIdentifierBathCount08 "      value="MeasurementIdentifierBathCount08 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementCount08 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementCount08 "  tabindex="257 " onfocus="calcNumberOfMeasurementCountSum() " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="AverageSizeOfMeasurementFootage08 "      value="AverageSizeOfMeasurementFootage08 " class="RentAVGFT " tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="AverageRentOfMeasurementAmount08 "      value="AverageRentOfMeasurementAmount08 " class="RentAVGFT " tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCount08 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCount08 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementVacantCount08 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementVacantCount08 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementDownCount08 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementDownCount08 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
               <td>
               <input type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCount08 "      value="NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCount08 "  tabindex="257 " /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <th colspan="2 ">Totals:</th>
               <td><input readonly type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementCountSum "      value="NumberOfMeasurementCountSum "  tabindex="409 " /></td>
               <td colspan="2 "><button type="button " id="CalculateTotals " onclick="calcNumberOfMeasurementCountSum(); calcNumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCountSum(); calcNumberOfMeasurementVacantCountSum(); calcNumberOfMeasurementDownCountSum(); calcNumberOfMeasurementInspectedCountSum(); ">Calculate Totals</button></td>
               <td><input readonly type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCountSum "      value="NumberOfMeasurementOccupiedCountSum "  tabindex="410 " /></td>
<td><input readonly type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementVacantCountSum " value="NumberOfMeasurementVacantCountSum "  tabindex="411 " /></td>
<td><input readonly type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementDownCountSum " value="NumberOfMeasurementDownCountSum "  tabindex="412 " /></td>
<td><input readonly type="text " name="NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCountSum " value="NumberOfMeasurementInspectedCountSum "  tabindex="413 " /></td>
          </tr>          
     </table>

     <p><input type="submit " value="Save Form " onclick="verify(); name="tbSubmit" tabindex="599" />
                    </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: This is the second part of the script for the sum calculation.

Answer (score 0):

the `document.getElementsByName`, as the name implies, returns many Elements, a `HTMLCollection` to be specific, which is an array-like structure. So you'll need to get the first item of that, like so:

```
document.getElementsByName("MeasurementUnitType")[0].value
```

or use `id` attributes and `getElementById`, which is what I would do, the mixing of `getElementById`is really confusing